# Extract sections of a file into separate files

Tags: performance, awk

I have a file of the form -

> >SDF123.1 blah blah
>
> ATCTCTGGAAACTCGGTGAAAGAGAGTAT
>
> AGTGATGAGGATGAGTGAG...
>
> >SBF123.1 blah blah
>
> ATCTCTGGAAACTCGGTGAAAGAGAGTAT
>
> AGTGATGAGGATGAGTGAG....

And I want to extract the various sections of this file into individual files (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21476033/splitting-a-multiple-fasta-file-into-separate-files-keeping-their-original-names)

I wrote the following code, but it runs too slow, as compared to when I did not have the `close` command in it. I had to incorporate the `close` command, since without it, I was getting the awk error - `too many open files`.

Here is the code -

```
cat C1_animal.fasta | awk -F ' ' '{
        if (substr($0, 1, 1)==">") {filename=(substr($1,2) ".fa")}
        print $0 >> filename; close (filename)
}'
```

How can I make this code more time efficient? I am new to awk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to close your `filename` only when it's necessary:

File `actg.awk`

```
BEGIN {
    FS=" "
}
/^>/ {
    if (filename != "") {
        close(filename)
    }
    filename = substr($1,2) ".fa"
    next
}
filename != "" {
    print $0 > filename
}
END {
    close (filename)
}
```

With shell command:

```bsh
awk -f actg.awk C1_animal.fasta
```

Note: if you are sure there is no line before the first "`> ...`", you can skip the `filename != " "` test

Comment: Thank you, this code worked nicely and was quite faster. Could you explain a little how this code works? I am still trying to laern awk